# Adding custom directory and PHP files in wordpress

Tags: php, themes, javascript, library

I'm new to WordPress and I'm using the latest version. I am trying to add this library https://github.com/pinceladasdaweb/tweetlight which is getting the latest tweets from Twitter. Tweets should be displayed at the index file. If you're going to look at the files, the necessary files include the `request.php` at the outside and the `api directory`. Where should I put them?

I tried putting them inside theme files but no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The github repo seems to be a custom code that you need drop into your theme directory, update your config file using your twitter credentials and try putting this code inside the body in any of your intended theme files that you will use(eg, index.php)

```
<h1>Tweets of a certain user</h1>
<div class="stream">
    <h2><span>Twitter</span></h2>
    <ul class="timeline"></ul>
</div>

<h1>Tweets of a certain user with profile image</h1>
<div class="stream">
    <h2><span>Twitter</span></h2>
    <ul class="timeline-profile-image"></ul>
</div>

<h1>HashTag: #html5</h1>
<div class="stream">
    <h2><span>Twitter</span></h2>
    <ul class="hashtag"></ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../build/tweetlight.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(window, document, undefined) {
        Tweetlight({
            username: 'pinceladasdaweb',
            container: '.timeline',
            counter: 5
        });
        Tweetlight({
            username: 'smashingmag',
            container: '.timeline-profile-image',
            showImageProfile: true,
            counter: 5
        });
        Tweetlight({
            hashtag: '#html5',
            container: '.hashtag',
            counter: 5
        });
    }(window, document));
</script>
```

I got the code from the example folder of the github repo

Comment: Hi @Carl, I already inserted the above code in index.php. My question is where should I put the `request.php` and the `api` folder?

Comment: You can try putting in the contents of request.php inside the header.php